# Параллельные insert/find у Splay дерева

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как можно реализовать работу с одним и тем же Splay деревом на разных потоках?

Само дерево находится [тут](http://pastebin.com/Ya1dGJap) (*код 200 строк классического дерева, потому я добавил ссылку на pastbin*)

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю:

1)что у нас делает flush(в методе synch).

комментарий в коде:

> ```
>    /*       * This function will be called as a "flush", with an intention
>     * to remove inter-thread inconsistencies.       */
> ```

2)не могу представить как можно параллельно в разных потоках вставлять и искать в одном и том же Splay дереве элементы, оно же всегда перетягивает узлы в корень. Причем важно, чтобы параллельное Splay  дерево работало быстрее классического...

**UPD:**

Я уточнил ограничения задания. В проекте имеется `main.cpp`:

```
#include "splayset.hpp"
#include "stopwatch.hpp"
#include "rc4prng.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>

const size_t concurrency = 4,
             item_count = 200000,
             group_size = 100,
             group_accesses = 2000,
             group_count = 1000;

const char rand_seed[] = "test ukolu";

void test_group (rc4prng<>& rng, splayset<uint64_t>&st)
{
    uint64_t begin = rng.random(), mult = rng.random();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < group_accesses; ++i)
        st.find (begin + mult * rng.random (group_size));
}

int main()
{
    splayset<uint64_t> st;

    rc4prng<> thread_rng[concurrency];
    for (size_t tid = 0; tid < concurrency; ++tid)
        thread_rng[tid].load_key (rand_seed, rand_seed + 10 - tid); // :]

    std::thread thread[concurrency];
    bpp::Stopwatch stopwatch (true);

    for (size_t tid = 0; tid < concurrency; ++tid)
        thread[tid] = std::thread ([tid, &thread_rng, &st]() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item_count; ++i)
            st.insert (thread_rng[tid].random());
    });

    for (size_t tid = 0; tid < concurrency; ++tid)
        thread[tid].join();

    stopwatch.stop();
    std::cout << stopwatch.getMiliseconds() << std::endl;
    stopwatch.start();

    for (size_t tid = 0; tid < concurrency; ++tid)
        thread[tid] = std::thread ([tid, &thread_rng, &st]() {
        for (size_t grp = 0; grp < group_count; ++grp)
            test_group (thread_rng[tid], st);
    });

    for (size_t tid = 0; tid < concurrency; ++tid)
        thread[tid].join();

    stopwatch.stop();
    std::cout << stopwatch.getMiliseconds() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Менять я могу только код самого дерева(не `main.cpp`), а следовательно у меня нету возможности сделать `worker` который будет заниматься диспечированием потоков внешне.

Совет @avp с использованием `scheduler` мне понравился, но я не знаю как его реализовать, при возможности модификации только имеющегося у меня `splayset.hpp`.

Если брать во внимание мое дополнение, можно ли как-то решить данное задание хотя бы частично эффективно?

Я очень надеюсь на совет, ибо я в тупике.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что конкретно этот код для  параллельной работы не годится.

Я бы подумал над модификацией с отложенным `splay()`, которая будет проводиться отдельным потоком, запускаемым при создании дерева (или в другой момент? вопрос открытый).

Для `find()` все довольно очевидно. Мы действительно можем, делая блокировку *только на чтение*, искать параллельно из нескольких потоков не мешая друг-другу. Данные о найденных каждым потоком несоответствиях в балансировке, для которых сейчас вызывается `splay()`, могут помещаться в очередь к потоку, который проводил бы балансировку отложено, т.е. когда запросов на поиск нет.

Если в том же духе посмотреть на `insert()`, то можно увидеть, что если узел не найден, то операция всегда выполняется с текущим листом, после чего вызывается `splay()` (т.е. ее можно тоже сделать отложенной и выполнять в том же потоке, что делает splay при поиске.)

Выполнение `erase()` (точнее ее части после `find()`) можно сделать аналогично.

Таким образом, вырисовывается архитектура с отдельным потоком модификации дерева, который берет запросы из очереди и выполняет их, установив монопольную блокировку всего дерева. Очевидно, что запросы insert и erase, начавшиеся с read-only блокировкой, поместив свои данные в очередь, должны эту блокировку снять и ждать завершения инициированной операции (вероятно, вместе со своим запросом они должны передавать condition variable, сигнала на которой (я говорю в терминах pthreads) они и будут дожидаться).

Возможно понадобится отдельный алгоритм оптимизации очереди запросов к "splay-потоку" (это отдельный вопрос, который придется тщательно продумать).

Еще один открытый вопрос тут, это алгоритм диспетчирования, который должен балансировать нагрузку между read-only потоками и "splay-потоком". Т.е. если в очереди накопилось достаточно данных и достаточно много потоков (insert/erase операции) ждут, то видимо надо приостановить поступление новых read-only операций к дереву.

А вот возможен ли прирост производительности при реализации такого плана?
 Если честно, не уверен. Возможно, для большого дерева с преобладанием запросов на успешный поиск выигрыш и будет.

**Update**

Утро вечера мудренее...
В самом деле мы можем не заморачиваться с созданием реального "splay-потока". Эту работу может выполнять любой существующий поток перед выходом из функций поиска-обновления.

Т.е. вызвав `splay()` можно либо добавить свои данные в очередь отложенных действий, либо, обнаружив, что как раз настал момент выполнять все эти действия, выполнить их в рамках этого потока. Естественно, поток должен обеспечить все необходимые блокировки и дождаться завершения работы с деревом другими потоками.

Возможно, для практики более подходит ограниченный подход к параллелизму. Операции модификации всегда выполняем с монопольной блокировкой, а поиск реализует отложенный `splay`.

Дополнительно, ту же очередь отложенных действий (в реальности это может быть массив  из десятка элементов) можно использовать и как кэш, проводя сначала последовательный поиск в ней.

Comment: Я добавил дополнение, ибо узнал об некоторых ограничениях на задание. Надеюсь на основе дополнения, вы сможете мне посоветовать оптимальный выход из положения

Comment: @Demolver, предложил update. А у Вас практическая задача или НИР? Дело в том, что на современных архитектурах последовательные массивы значительно быстрее, чем структуры  разбросанные по памяти. Например, и ArrayList в Java и списки в Python реализованы векторами.

Comment: Практическая, причем цель именно научить `splay` дерево работать при вызове его из разных потоков (дерево является общим для всех потоков). Я думал о `mutex`, но блокировать все дерево ради `splay`? Плюс если я верно понимаю, то мне нужно сделать очередь из ссылок на узлы для `splay`... но если `splay` для одного и того же узла происходит несколько раз но в разном порядке, то нужно как то определить порядок очереди и редактировать его...

Comment: @Demolver, безусловно, порядок (особенно для операций модификации) нужно учитывать. Однако, раз уж речь о практике..., посмотрите на последние 2 абзаца update. Если сделать кэш для find, то там одинаковые ссылки будут присутствовать один раз. Опять же о практике... Выигрыш для многопоточных реализаций может быть только если потоки разделяют данные минимально. Скажем, если это происходит раз в миллисекунду (ну, м.б. немного чаще), а все остальное время они молотят каждый  свои данные. Иначе накладные расходы на синхронизацию (и volatile с памятью) все съедят.